# Как поместить окно tkinter поверх окон других приложений?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Нужно создать окно, которое находилось бы всегда поверх окон других запущенных приложений. Можно ли это реализовать с помощью tkinter'a ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    from tkinter import*
except:
    from Tkinter import*
root=Tk()
root.attributes("-topmost",True)
root.mainloop()
```